# Rank in GQL query google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

i need to use the rank function in the gql query..

SELECT * FROM ScoreBoard WHERE finish = True ORDER BY attempts

how do i get the the rank for each and every record.. is there any function like rank similar to MS SQL..

Answer (score 0):

There's no efficient way to do this short of fetching all the entities and numbering them sequentially - that's all 'rank' does in SQL. Instead, you should precompute, using a library like [app-engine-ranklist](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-ranklist/).